# Rails library or gem to work with zip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zip

What is in Rails or in Ruby to work with zip. For example in the PHP is pclzip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [RubyZip](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

i made a gem to create streaming zip files in rails: http://github.com/fringd/zipline